# Writing into stdout with MFC and read stdout by python Popen

Tags: python, mfc

I want to write into `std::cerr` or `std::cout` with my MFC application. In a python script I call this application and I want to read from `stdout` or `stderr`.
Both is not working. Just using `std::cout` yields no output. After `AllocConsole()` I was at least able to print to a debug console. Unfortunately, there is still no output on the python site.

In my MFC application I initialize a console to write to with this code:

```
void BindStdHandlesToConsole()
{
  // Redirect the CRT standard input, output, and error handles to the console
  freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
  freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
  freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);

  std::wcout.clear();
  std::cout.clear();
  std::wcerr.clear();
  std::cerr.clear();
  std::wcin.clear();
  std::cin.clear();
}

// initialization
BOOL foo::InitInstance()
{
  // allocate a console
  if (!AllocConsole())
    AfxMessageBox("Failed to create the console!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
  else 
    BindStdHandlesToConsole();
```

On the python site, I try to print the output.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)    
output = process.stdout.read()
process.wait()
```

Is there a way to make my MFC program really write and the python script read the standard output?

Comment: Try setting `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` as well and then using `(output, error) = process.communicate()` without the `read()` and the `.wait()`.

Comment: Still no output :(

Comment: Are you testing `output` and `error`?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of writing stuff to stdout pipe is the following:

```
HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
WriteFile( hStdOut, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL );
```